# Run Livewire click method based on whether a checkbox is checked or not

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I have a Livewire component like below

```php
<div class="mr-3">
    <input type="checkbox" name="milestoneMark" value="{{ $milestoneId }}" x-model="milestone" wire:click="mark()">
</div>
```

The component class have below code

```php
class CheckMilestone extends Component
{

    public $milestoneId;

    public function mark()
    {
        $milestone = Milestone::where('id', $this->milestoneId)
            ->first();

        $user = User::where('id', auth()->id())
            ->first();

        $user->milestones()->attach($milestone);

    }

    public function unMark()
    {
        $milestone = Milestone::where('id', $this->milestoneId)
            ->first();

        $user = User::where('id', auth()->id())
            ->first();

        $user->milestones()->detach($milestone);

    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.check-milestone');
    }
}
```

My requirement is execute `mark()` method when the checkbox is unchecked and execute `unMark()` when the checkbox is checked

I tried below but didn't work

```php
<div class="mr-3">
    <input type="checkbox" name="milestoneMark" value="{{ $milestoneId }}" x-model="milestone" {!!  'checked' ? wire:click="mark()" : wire:click="unMark()" !!} >
</div>
```

I try to use as less JavaScript as possible so if you can please give me a solution without JS, but if there isn't any other way to fix this I'm okay to use JS. TIA!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have nothing to base your checked situation from. I personally would do the following:

```php
class CheckMilestone extends Component
{

    public $milestoneId;
    public bool $checked = false;

    public function processMark()
    {
        if ($this->checked) {
            $this->mark();
        } else {
            $this->unMark();
        }

    }

    // Rest of your code here
}
```

```html
<div class="mr-3">
    <input type="checkbox" wire:model="checked" wire:change="processMark()" wire:loading.attr="disabled">
</div>
```

To explain; we use `wire:model` to link the value of the checkbox to the Livewire component. We use `wire:change` to detect the change event triggered when you (de)select the checkbox, and fire the `processMark` method. Purposely we don't change the HTML as to not cause unexpected behaviour. We use `wire:loading` to add the disabled attribute while the `checked` variable is being updated, so we can't quickly uncheck it while it's processing.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use `wire:model.live="milestoneMark"` to send live value to livewire component and then intercept the new value on change using the Lifecycle function `updatedMilestoneMark()` then you do your stuff depending on the `$milestoneMark` value

Lifecycle Hooks : https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/lifecycle-hooks

Live-updating fields: https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/forms#live-updating-fields

Good luck!